# what are the differences between ないでもいい and なくてもいい?

Tags: grammar

Ive seen this sentence 強がら**ないでいい**.

I wondered
Would there be any difference if i replaced it with 強がら**なくていい**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

強がらないで(も)いい and 強がらなくて(も)いい mean the same thing, and are interchangeable. More generally, (し)ないでいい and (し)なくていい are always interchangeable. The former is probably more common in informal settings, but both are perfectly natural.

(Of course, that is not to say ないで and なくて are always the same. See [these search results](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%22%20%22%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%22).)